# Trying to serialize a object (save it toi a file) , getting exception that says read only file systrem

Tags: android

I'm trying to save an object to a file in my android code.  When I try to Open the output stream `FileOutputStream("test.obj");` it throws an exception saying read-only file system.

```
try {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("test.obj"); // exception goes off here
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);

    out.writeObject(mShareSecurity);

    out.close();
    file.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    mesg=e.getMessage();
    ted++;
}
```

Comment: What type of file are you trying to create? Are you checking read/write permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No chance that it is related to Object serialization.

- Ensure that you have permissions to write, for the app, may be WRTIE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
- Check path and make sure that you are writing to intended location, use File.getAbsolutePath().

Answer (score 0):

> it throws an exception saying read-only file system.

This is related to permission, try to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest file and runtime permission:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

The other way to save the file can be achieved by saving it to internal storage with:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("test.obj", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);

    out.writeObject(mShareSecurity);

    out.close();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO: don't forget to handle the exception!
}
```

Please read more about it at [Save file on device storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java).